# how to upgrade version of composer

Tags: composer-php

I was trying to require a package using `composer require` command, and I faced following error

> your version of
> Composer is too old Please upgrade using https://getcomposer.org/

How can I update composer itself?

I am using Linux Mint 18.3.

Comment: https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#self-update-selfupdate-

Answer (score 29):

Use this command to update the version of composer:

```
composer self-update
```

Comment: Command "self-update" is not defined.

Answer (score 6):

The best way is using this command:  `composer self-update --stable`

Comment: Command "self-update" is not defined.

Answer (score 5):

It's now new version of composer. So anyone want to upgrade the composer, should use this command:

```
composer self-update --2
```

Comment: `--2: Force an update to the stable channel, but only use 2.x versions`

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to update the version of the composer:
Specially on Mac or Ubuntu it's better to go with sudo command:

```
sudo composer self-update
```

Answer (score 0):

If `composer self-update` doesn't work (error is that `self-update` is not defined) then follow the steps below for manually downloading and updating composer to latest stable version

```
cd ~
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer -o /tmp/composer-setup.php
```

Next verify that the downloaded installer matches the SHA-384 hash for the latest installer found on the Composer Public Keys / Signatures page.

```
HASH=`curl -sS https://composer.github.io/installer.sig`
```

Execute the following PHP code to verify that the installation script is safe to run:

```
php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', '/tmp/composer-setup.php') === '$HASH') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
```

If you get `Installer verified` then run final command to have Composer as a system-wide command named composer, under /usr/local/bin:

```
sudo php /tmp/composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

Restart your shell and run `composer --version` to verify

@see https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-composer-on-ubuntu-20-04-quickstart